# Find command : special characters do not work as expected

Tags: regex, ubuntu, find

I am trying to search some files in a specific directory called `Dico` with `find` command e.g.

- I want to find all files ending with `g` : `find ./Dico -name "*g` works but `find ./Dico -name ".*g` or `find ./Dico -name ".*g$` do not. Can someone explain me why ?
- Another example would be to find : all files that start with a number followed by exactly 5 characters (lowercase) :  `find ./Dico -name "\[0-9\]+[a-z]\{5\}"` or `find ./Dico -name "\d+[a-z]{5}"`. In that case `+`, `\d+` and `{n}` do seem to do nothing.. I've tried both `{5}` and `\{5\}` (emacs syntax) but still the special characters seem to not work correctly.

I am on Ubuntu 20.04. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I have also tried ```find ./Dico -type f -regex "g$"``` and still does not return what I expected.

Comment: You should really use `'` as a string delimiter when you intend to escape all of its content instead of `"`. Try that and it should work.

Comment: @BlackBeans just tried ```find ./Dico -name '\[0-9\]+[a-z]\{5\}'``` and still does not work..

Comment: for this one, just do `man find` (hint: search for `regex`). Note: a shell pattern is not a regular expression.

Comment: @BlackBeans thak you. Apparently I was trying to merge shell patterns with regexes.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `-name` does not use regex.

> `-name pattern`
> Base of file name (the path with the leading directories removed) matches **shell pattern** `pattern`.

A matching shell pattern could look like this:

```
find /Dico -name '[0-9][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z]'
```

To use regex, you need to instead use the `-regex` option (and `-regextype` to select the regex dialect you want).

> `-regex pattern`
> File name matches regular expression pattern. This is a match on the whole path, not a search.

I selected the regex dialect `egrep`:

```
find /Dico -regextype egrep -regex '.*/[0-9]+[a-z]{5}'
```

You can do `find -regextype help` (or just about any invalid dialect) to get a list of the supported regex dialects.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This works as expected, but I was trying to recreate the same result with ```find``` command.

Comment: @Artemis You're welcome. What does _"but I was trying to recreate the same result with `find` command"_ mean? The above is all about the `find` command.

Comment: Yes you are right, I meant with shell patterns.

Comment: @Artemis Now I'm confused. You tagged the question [tag:regex] and also used regex to try to find the file. If you are actually trying to use a shell pattern to match the file, then why tag it regex? Anyway, I updated the answer with a matching shell pattern.

Comment: @Artemis Did the shell pattern work?